# number_format return the wrong value?

Tags: php, number-formatting

This is my code:

```
$subTotal = number_format($subTotal, 2);
```

In $subTotal I had a value like 1,233.00 as a string. The return value was 1.00, which of course is wrong. So I tried something else:

```
$subTotal = number_format($subTotal, 2, '.', ',');
```

Result is still the same. How can I make it work with a , as thousand separator?

Thanks!

Comment: number_format() works on numeric data types, not on formatted strings.... if you provide a formatted string to number_format() then it will be cast to a numeric using normal PHP casting rules (as defined in the documentation), which means that anything after a comma will be ignored

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the commas before you call `number_format()`

```
$subTotal = number_format(str_replace(',', '', $subTotal), 2);
```

Comment: Because PHP treats that value as a string. But number_format() wants an integer. So it converts that value to an integer. But that means truncating the number at the first non-digit it finds which is the comma.